# Font size without using @media queries?

Tags: html, css, email, responsive-design, typography

Goal is to have button that is resized depending on the screen size without using `@media` queries due to the reason Email is built half-way with a specific tool and the main `style` set isn't editable.

This means that it's not possible to set a content specific `style` tag for the button, as Gmail app for Android will [ignore all secondary style tags](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/12_things_you_must_know_when_developing_for_gmail_and_gmail_mobile_apps-2/).

I've found it should be possible with [Viewport typography](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) but for some reason not matter what I've tried, the font size doesn't change on the Android Gmail app.

I suspect the screen resolution is one thing (2960x1440) and possibly also that I cannot add inline `viewport` to the style.

Current button code:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-radius:3px; background-color:#E4E4E4;">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">
      <a href="google.com" target="_blank" style="color:#000000; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-size: 1.4vw; font-weight:bold; line-height: 100%; background-color: #E4E4E4; border: 3px solid #000000; padding: 8px 20px; border-radius: 0px; -moz-border-radius: 0px; -webkit-border-radius: 0px;  text-decoration:none; ">CLICK HERE</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is there anything else I could try here?

Comment: `font-size` in `vw` unit doesn't solve your problem? you needd just to find the correct `font-size` value in `vw` and it will automatically expand the button depending on the screen resolution

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a working solution with real text.

But you might get along with an image – not very elegant though:

```html
<body>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-radius:3px; background-color:#E4E4E4;">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">
      <a href="google.com" target="_blank" style="line-height: 100%;"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo7mJ.png" alt="Click Here" style="width:10%; height: auto; min-width:100px; vertical-align: middle; padding: 1.5% 3%; border: 3px solid #000000;  border-radius: 0px; display: inline-block; margin: -1% auto; background-color:#E4E4E4;"/></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Sadly HTML for email is no fun.